# loop iterate 5 times in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am learning `reactjs` and i have created one module for society maintenance billing,in this module i wanted to fetch all society members name and changes that i wanted to apply on all that members.i have fetch all that details but now i wanted to count the total amount of charges applied on every users.But my problem is that my loop iterate 5 time i don't understand why this happens

Here is my code:

```
  handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
    }


countTotal(){

   this.state.chargeInputs.map((charge) => {
     var chargeTotal = 0;
    for(var val in charge){

        console.log('actual amt'+charge.charge_amt); //this lines print for 5 times

        chargeTotal +=  parseInt(charge.charge_amt);

        console.log('total'+parseInt(chargeTotal)); //this lines print for 5 times
        this.setState({ Total: chargeTotal});

    }

  });
}
  render() {

    return (
        <div className="content">
            <NavBar></NavBar>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-10">
                    <div className="card">
                        <div className="card-header card-header-icon" data-background-color="rose">
                            <i className="material-icons">receipt</i>
                        </div>
                        <div className="card-content">
                            <h4 className="card-title">Add Bill</h4>
                            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmitFirebase}>
                                <div className="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick={this.appendUserInput}><i className="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>Load Users</a>
                                    <div className="room-main">
                                        <div className="online-est">
                                            <select className="room-form">
                                                {this.renderUserInput()}
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <span className="material-input"></span></div>
                                <div className="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick={this.appendBillInput}><i className="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>Load Charges</a>
                                    <div className="room-main">
                                        <div className="online-est">
                                            {this.renderChargeInput()}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <span className="material-input"></span></div>
                                <div className="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                                    <label className="control-label">status</label>
                                    <select className="online-est" ref={el => this.status = el}>
                                        <option value="Unpaid">Unpaid</option>
                                        <option value="Paid">Paid</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <span className="material-input"></span></div>
                                    <div className="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                                        <label className="control-label">Total</label>
                                        <input type="text" className="form-control" ref={el => this.Total = el} onClick={this.countTotal} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                                        <span className="material-input"></span></div>
                                <div className="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                                    <label className="control-label">Bill due date</label>
                                    <input type="date" className="form-control" ref={el => this.billdue = el} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                                    <span className="material-input"></span></div>
                                <div className="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                                    <label className="control-label">Bill period</label>
                                    <input type="date" className="form-control" ref={el => this.billto = el} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                                    <input type="date" className="form-control" ref={el => this.billfrom = el} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                                    <span className="material-input"></span></div>
                                <div className="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                                    <span className="material-input"></span></div>
                                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-fill btn-rose">Submit</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Output:

```js
actual amt2
total2
actual amt2
total4
actual amt2
total6
actual amt2
total8
actual amt2
total10
actual amt1001
total1001
actual amt1001
total2002
actual amt1001
total3003
actual amt1001
total4004
actual amt1001
total5005
actual amt1200

total1200
actual amt1200
total2400
actual amt1200
total3600
actual amt1200
total4800
actual amt1200
total6000
actual amt200
total200
actual amt200
total400
actual amt200
total600
actual amt200
total800
actual amt200
total1000
actual amt100
total100
actual amt100
total200
actual amt100
total300
actual amt100
total400
actual amt100
```

Comment: which loop iterate 5 times? little bit unclear the exact issue you are facing.

Comment: i am iterating loop in countTotal() and that loop iterate for 5 times. i have updated my code please check

Comment: this is because you are using nested loops, for inside map that's why.

Comment: `for(var val in charge){` is doing your 5 time loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issues:**

1- You are doing `setState` inside loop, that is not a good idea/pattern, first do all the computation then use `setState` to update the state value. Always try to use `setState` once inside a function, at the end.

2- Reason why that line is printing 5 times is, you are using nested loop `for...in` inside `map`.

I think `for...in` loop is not required, because you are not using the val anywhere inside the `for...in` body. Also instead of using map, better to use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Write it like this:

```
countTotal(){
    var chargeTotal = 0;
    this.state.chargeInputs.forEach(charge => {

        chargeTotal +=  parseInt(charge.charge_amt);
        console.log('total', parseInt(chargeTotal)); 

    })
    this.setState({ Total: chargeTotal});
}
```

Comment: yes i did the same after posting here but i dont find total value also

Comment: *dont find total value also*, can you explain, console is not printing the values?

Comment: no,console prints the values but it does not count the total. the old value is printing only .As u can see i have console the actual amt and total amnt but my both values are same like this actual amt345

actual amt525
total525
actual amt300
total300 I have just remove the for loop

Comment: have you defined the `var chargeTotal = 0;` outside of `forEach` loop ??  because that should work, try using the same snippet.

Comment: glad, you got the solution :)